# npm doesn't give any output on windows (command fails with exit code 1)

Tags: node.js, npm

I've recently installed nodejs v18.12.1 on Windows 11 but the npm command doesn't give any output.
Running it with vscode terminal I can see that the command fails with exit code 1.

I've tried to reinstall nodejs several times, using nvm or in a conda environment but the npm command always fails:
[npm -v no output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tIC1.jpg)
[npm -v exit 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kemgB.gif)

please help me fix this problem

Comment: One of the perfect methods to install and update node.js is using NVM. Please! Try method #3 in the link below:

https://www.newline.co/@Adele/how-to-install-nodejs-and-npm-on-macos--22782681

Answer (score 0):

One of the perfect methods to install and update node.js is using NVM.
Please! Try method #3 in the link below:

https://www.newline.co/@Adele/how-to-install-nodejs-and-npm-on-macos--22782681